# Tools for measuring test coverage of VDHL code

Tags: unit-tests, code-coverage

I need to measure the code coverage of [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl) code. 
Especially the following metrics are interesting:

- Statement coverage
- Branch coverage
- MC/DC coverage
- Toggle coverage

The only tool (of which I am aware) that is capable of measuring these metrics is [ModelSim](https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/modelsim/).

Tool are allowed to run on Linux or Windows.

**Question**

Are there other tools available, that are capable of measuring these code coverage metrics? Open source solution are interesting too.

Comment: What OS should it run on? Any price limit?

Comment: That's hard to achieve (and outside the scope of this site IMHO). OK, so let's put it this way: You prefer "free" solutions but wouldn't object to a "reasonable price" you cannot yet name, and which of course depends on quality/features offered by the product. Would that match your intention?

Comment: The price is not interesting at the moment. First I want to find tools that are capable of measuring code coverage.

Comment: How would you expect such a tool to operate?  Guessing from the site, Modelsim uses a built-in VHDL simulator to track the execution and gives you coverage statistics.  Are you expecting to find another simulator that can provide this?  If not, how do you expect coverage statistics to be collected?

Answer (score 3):

[GHDL code coverage](http://home.mnet-online.de/al/ghdl_gcov/ghdl_gcov.html) claims it produces line coverage for VHDL, using an extension to the GCC VHDL compiler.

I don't know anything about it except that this website exists.

Comment: Thanks, the project seems to be too old. The post is from July 2005 and uses gcc-3.3. I doubt that it is really usable anymore with a modern environment.

Comment: I take it this means you want something off the shelf that just runs.  (Often "open source" means "i can tinker with it to make it work").  Can you respond to my question on "how the tool should operate"?

Comment: Apparantly it is not too old.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38854385/120163, where a report of its operation is made this month of Aug 2016.

Comment: "I doubt that it is really usable anymore with a modern environment" - I doubt that you have tried.  You don't have many options here; doesn't it behoove you to at least try?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveHDL does this too. App note here: https://www.aldec.com/en/support/resources/documentation/articles/1012